# how to push kill-ring contents onto system pasteboard (clipboard)?

Tags: copy-paste, kill-ring, clipboard

I use the brilliant answer from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849281/on-emacs-for-osx-how-to-keep-kill-ring-and-clipboard-separate/) to copy selected regions of text from Emacs onto my system pasteboard (i.e. the OSX clipboard).

But some functions (e.g. gist-buffer) push output (e.g. a URL) onto the Emacs kill ring, and I'd like to be able to access that text from other OSX apps. (Without having to do yank, highlight region, then `pbcopy` like I currently do.)

So: How can I push text directly from the Emacs kill-ring to the OSX pasteboard?

Comment: Hmm, I always thought that newer versions of Emacs put contents of kill ring into clipboard by default, at least this is how it works for me. I'm using GNU/Linux, though.

Comment: Maybe they do, but I guess I'm not using default settings. I'd Iike to do this manually.

Comment: This may be of some interest for you: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `x-select-text` can be used to do this:

```
Select TEXT, a string, according to the window system.

On X, if `x-select-enable-clipboard' is non-nil, copy TEXT to the
clipboard.  If `x-select-enable-primary' is non-nil, put TEXT in
the primary selection.
```

So we need to set`x-select-enable-clipboard` to a non-nil value (e.g., `t`). 
On Linux machines, it's set to `t` by default, so you may or may not need to do this.

```el
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)

(defun copy-current-kill-to-clipboard ()
  (interactive)
  (x-select-text (current-kill 0)))
```

I don't have an OSX machine to test on -- only Linux --, but this should all work the same on OSX.

Comment: This won't work for me, since I have interprogram-cut-function and interprogram-paste-function set to nil. So I need to push the kill ring to the pasteboard manually.

Comment: I updated the answer to include code to do that.

Comment: PSA: `x-select-enable-clipboard` var name is getting deprecated in emacs 25+ and is being replaced with `select-enable-clipboard`. Similarly `x-select-enable-primary` -> `select-enable-primary`.

Comment: So what's a better way to code it?

Answer (score 1):

I think [gui-set-selection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-System-Selections.html) is your friend:

> — Command: gui-set-selection type data This function sets a
>   window-system selection. It takes two arguments: a selection type
>   type, and the value to assign to it, data.
>
> type should be a symbol; it is usually one of PRIMARY, SECONDARY or
>   CLIPBOARD. These are symbols with upper-case names, in accord with X
>   Window System conventions. If type is nil, that stands for PRIMARY.
>
> If data is nil, it means to clear out the selection. Otherwise, data
>   may be a string, a symbol, an integer (or a cons of two integers or
>   list of two integers), an overlay, or a cons of two markers pointing
>   to the same buffer. An overlay or a pair of markers stands for text in
>   the overlay or between the markers. The argument data may also be a
>   vector of valid non-vector selection values.
>
> This function returns data.

So

```
(defun copy-current-kill-to-clipboard ()
(interactive)
(gui-set-selection 'CLIPBOARD (current-kill 0)))
```

should do the job without any prerequisites (e.g. x-select-enable-clipboard being t).